# Updating database by editing datagridview datasource in VB.Net and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I don't know if my question is correct but is it possible to update my database using a datagridview with datasource in VB.NET.

By displaying my data from database i use the following code which work as expected:

```
Public Sub LoadResult()
    Dim summaryTable As New DataTable
    SummaryGrid.DataSource = summaryTable
End Sub
```

Now I'm working with this code to update database.

First, I'm trying to store the result from datagridview to an array of string

```
Dim str As New List(Of String)
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In SummaryGrid.Rows
    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
        str.Add(row.Cells(0).Value)
        str.Add(row.Cells(1).Value)
        str.Add(row.Cells(2).Value)
        str.Add(row.Cells(3).Value)
    End If
 Next
```

Now the update code, I don't how to deal with this one, seems very difficult for me

```
    If str.Count > 0 Then
       //any help here
       Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("", connection)

       End Using
    End If
```

Or maybe I should use insert query, Insert the updated datagridview data to a new table instead of updating the current table data.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked into the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace yet?

Comment: @ParrishHusband Yes I have the following namespaces; System.Data and System.Data.SqlClient, I am trying to use DataBinding but there is  a lot to modify. thats why I stick to that approach.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to update data in database using `DatagridView`. Anyways, as @ParrishHusband said, What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post some of the code you've tried for writing to the database.  The code you posted appears to be what you said was already working.

Comment: @ParrishHusband, see edits

Comment: @RichardBaluyut, see edit